# Selenium parsing - how to find elements by one class and return other class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

All,

I am trying to scrape a dynamic retail webpage using Selenium. I am trying to grab a list of all items with the particular class name "product-name." The website's html reads like this: 
[image: example of lines with tags and class names I'm interested in]

From the attached example, what I would want is the product name/title: "COACH X KEITH HARING CHARLIE CARRYALL IN SIGNATURE PATCHWORK." I want this for every product on the page. To do this I can either search for the "title" field, or the "content" field in the line with the `meta` tag. This being said, I'm new to Selenium and don't know how to pull this. All I know of is the find_elements_by... command, but I think it will only return the field I specify/search for. My code is supposed to return all the product names from this webpage, so I need some way to specify how to identify where the titles/product names are, and then a way to pull these fields.

Using BeautifulSoup I could search by one class name and retrieve the value of some other specified class, but I don't know how to use Selenium in this way. I figure I need to use Selenium instead of BeautifulSoup because the website is dynamic. Is there some functionality built into Selenium like the .findAll() command from BeautifulSoup, that can be used to retrieve one field name from a line using another specified field name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your code so far and the URL you're trying to parse?

Comment: Here is what I had: `namesElements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-name']")` Regarding @Tarun Lalwani's suggestion, I did not know there was this feature using the "/." When I first read about this feature, it didn't mean much to me. Now seeing this example, however, it does.  For anyone looking into this in the future, this page lists a number of different ways to use xpath: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Please don't post updates to your question in comments. It makes it harder for the next reader to find. Instead edit your question and add the details there. You can then add a comment stating that you've updated the question with XXX info, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this using a nice, compact CSS selector. They are faster than XPath and I find them much easier to read.

```
products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("meta[itemprop='name']")
for product in products:
    print(product.get_attribute("content"))
```

We're basically looking for this `META` tag

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="COACH X KEITH HARING ACADEMY BACKPACK">
```

using the `itemprop` attribute and then pulling the `content` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple and basic xpath

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-name']/meta[@itemprop='name']")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("content"))
```

Comment: There is no `title` attribute on the `META` tag... and I don't think `.get()` will get the attribute anyway.

Comment: It should be content actually. By mistake typo